# Why "click","delegate" and "live" behave differently in terms of event bubbling using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I wrote a sample JavaScript program to demostrate the confusingly different event bubbling behavior of jQuery's function, `click`, `delegate` and `live`.

Here is the [demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/xiaohan2012/aNvnJ/2/).

For each function, there is a *wrapper* and a *click link* in the wrapper, both of which are registered with click event functions.

I notice that

1. Using `stopPropagation` in `live` and `delegate` does not prevent event bubbling
2. In `live` and `delegate`, the click event in the wrapper is fired first and the *click link* next. However, this order is reversed for `click` function.

Can anyone explain these two phenomenon?

The sample is using jQuery 1.6.4, but you can adjust the version.

Comment: The jQuery [doco for .`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) explains this - did you look at the doco before posting your question?

Comment: I tried but found it a little hard to understand...

Answer (score 2):

To start, [live is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in favor of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in jQuery 1.7+. I would stop using `live` now rather than later. The docs linked above are actually very informative and do a great job of explaining how these functions work.

Delegate and live both rely on bubbling. Which is how they differ from click. The event has bubbled up to them. Delegate is superior to live because you tell it to monitor a specific parent whereas live bubbles all the way up to the document level. Very expensive.

The jQuery documentation is worth quoting here:

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers,
>   therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by
>   calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the implementation of live and delegate then you would understand the reason for this difference. Live and delegate in a way are not attached to the element because the element is not there at the time of binding they are attached to either the root or a specific parent respectively and hence the difference. And they make use of event bubbling so that when event bubbles from child to the root or a specific parent it executes for the newly added element see this blog entry for a detailed view around this:

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/